# Execute external javascript embedded in inline html from .net Maui windows desktop application

Tags: c#, windows, maui

I have an Html code embedded in C# .net MAUI windows desktop application. The Html references to external javascript files but this code doesn't work in .net MAUI solution for windows desktop app. any possible leads to this problem? The .js files are placed under Resources/Raw folder and have a build action MauiAsset.

As per the micrsoft documentation the javascript files are placed under Resources/Raw folder and are referenced correctly with the file name as the source in Html code that is written within C# .net maui solution. Expecting to execute these .js files code and produce the output.

Code snippet as below:

```
     string chartJsScript = "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />" +
"<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;'/>" +

"<meta http-equiv = \"X-UA-Compatible\" content =\"ie=edge\" />    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src =\"chart.min.js\"> </script>" +


        "<script src =\"chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js\"> </script>    <script src=\"Chart.roundedBarCharts.js\"> </script>";
            string chartContent = $@"<div id=""chart-container"" >
   <canvas id=""{chartname}""></canvas> </div>";
            string customlegend = "";
           
                customlegend = "<div style=\"text-align:center;\"  id=\"legend\"></div>";

            var document = $@"<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
  <head>{chartJsScript}</head>
  <body>

    {chartContent}
{customlegend}

   {chartConfig}
  </body>
 

</html>";
```

Comment: `but this code doesn't work ` What exactly is your problem? Can you elaborate on that?    And how can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or more code snippets s that we can try to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Yes sure ...will post the code snippet

Comment: Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?